# Cloudera Hue - cannot recognize input near 'WITH' 'SERDEPROPERTIES' '(' in serde properties specification

Tags: hive, ddl, create-table, hive-serde, hiveddl

I'm trying to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE
    TABLE_DATA
    (
        A STRING,
        B STRING,
        C STRING,
        D STRING,
        E STRING,
        F STRING,
        G STRING,
        H STRING,
    )
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
    (
       "separatorChar" = ",",
       "quoteChar"     = "\""
    )       
    STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '...'
    TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

However I'm getting an issue:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 14:2
>   cannot recognize input near 'WITH' 'SERDEPROPERTIES' '(' in serde
>   properties specification

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: remove this:  `STORED AS TEXTFILE` and this: `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROW FORMAT should be specified once, and remove extra comma after last column

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_DATA
            (
                    A STRING,
                    B STRING,
                    C STRING,
                    D STRING,
                    E STRING,
                    F STRING,
                    G STRING,
                    H STRING
            )
            ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
            WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
            (
               "separatorChar" = ",",
               "quoteChar"     = "\""
            )       
            LOCATION '...'
            TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```